# Interactive System Arguments in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, sys

I have written a code which is to be run from the command prompt, taking arguments from the command.

What i have tried.

```
start_date = sys.argv[1]
end_date = sys.argv[2]

end_date2 = datetime.strptime(end_date, "%d %b %Y").date()
start_date2 = datetime.strptime(start_date, "%d %b %Y").date()
--- Do Something ---
```

and i am running the script thus :

```
python myscript.py "19 Aug 2016" "19 Sep 2016"
```

this runs smoothly. however whatever i am doing in the script requires a condition :-- `start_date2 > end_date2`

so i am using a if statement to restrict this and `exit()` the code if the above condition is not met.

My Question :-

Is it possible to reset the argument if the above condition is not met??

something like :

```
if start_date2 < end_date2 :
    re enter the arguments from the command prompt 
    without stopping the code and take the new arguments and ignore the  wrong ones.
```

kind of like an interactive code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. Simply after detecting dates are wrong use `print`/`raw_input` and ask user for new date, overwrite old one and check dates again.

For example (pseudocode a bit):

```
start_date = sys.argv[1]
while start_date.isWrong():
    print "start_date is wrong, gimme new one and press enter: "
    start_date = parse_from_string(raw_input())
```

Anyway, you should try [argparse](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/argparse.html) to read command-line options.

Comment: I have been recommended "argparse" by some other people as well. However i do not find any significant difference in performance of the code. Could you please tell me the what difference it would make??

Comment: Yes. Argparse is made for getting data from user and offers many good things - dispalying help, warning user if he doesn't give you args, checking format, converting to proper format, giving you good api to get data (e.g. args.date_from is better then sys.argv[1])… Give it a try and you'll see :)